# jQuery xss Issue on table.rows[i] line

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss, fortify

jQuery version 3.2.1

I ran my HP fortify SCA and I got a **Cross-Site Scripting: DOM** issue on my html file.

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Row1 cell1</td>
    <td>Row1 cell2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var row = $(document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0]);
}
</script>
```

The report shows that the problem is `.rows[0]` and jQuery selector `$()`

```
$(document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0])
```

Googling, I found that jQuery had xss issue in old version.

But I'm not sure that is my code has a vulnerability or not?

If it has a vulnerability, how xss happen in this case?

**Edit:** According to the comment below, I edited `$(document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0])` to `$($('#myTable')[0].rows[0]);`
But fortify still report same issue.

Comment: You are mixing up `jQuery` and `JavaScript` togther! what is your expected output here ?

Comment: If you want the first row, try `var row = $('#myTable tr:first-child')`.

Comment: In fact, this is a problem with jqGrid. I tried to analyze the problem and found that their vulnerability are both in ```rows[0]``` and ```$()```. So I wrote a simple code to scan, and found that the vulnerability were also scanned. I want to know if this problem is false positives or it can really be attacked.

jqGrid code is something like ```$($t.rows[i]).css("display","none");```